# How can I combine two arrays and output stored values as it`s written in description. May be there are some ways to do that?

Tags: c, arrays, max

Task description -> [Whole task description is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNKxn.png)

I have done part with sorting and got stuck.
How can I combine these arrays in one of already sorted pairs?

---

```
printf("\nHeight of boys in descending order\n");

for (i = (LENGTH1 - 1); i >= 0; i--)
{
    printf("%d ", heightBoys[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < LENGTH2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < (LENGTH2 - j - 1); j++)
    { 
        if (heightGirls[j] > heightGirls[j+1])
        {
            temp = heightGirls[j];
            heightGirls[j] = heightGirls[j+1];
            heightGirls[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

printf("\nHeight of girls in descending order\n");

for (j = (LENGTH2 - 1); j >= 0; j--)
{
    printf("%d ", heightGirls[j]);
}
```

Comment: Please provide information here, instead via a link which might die.

Comment: How did you get stuck? What are the symptoms?

Comment: Where is the description you are referring to?

Comment: @Yunnosch I have tried

Comment: How did it fail? What were the symptoms? (Do you see a pattern here?)

Comment: Please study the concept of making a [mcve].

Comment: @Yunnoschit does not fail, I`m just asking how what are possible ways to solve this problem(outputting paired heights in descending way)?

Comment: Let's try again: 1) Pleae provide information here, instead via link 2) Please describe how you got stuck, by listing the observed symptoms. 3) Please make a MCVE as described in the link I provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sort [for the girls], but it is broken. Change:

```
for (j = 0; j < (LENGTH2 - j - 1); j++)
```

Into:

```
for (j = 0; j < (LENGTH2 - i - 1); j++)
```

To avoid [needless] replication of code, put the sorting code into a separate function.

Sort both arrays.

Take the minimum of the lengths of the two arrays (e.g. `minlen`).

I'm not sure what you mean [exactly] by "pairing", but the simplest is to *print* the pairing

Then, just loop on:

```
for (i = 0;  i < minlen;  ++i)
    printf("Girl:%d Boy:%d\n",heightGirls[i],heightBoys[i]);
```

If you needed something more complex, you might need an array of `struct`s like:

```
struct pair {
    int boyheight;
    int girlheight;
};
```

This array would need to be at least `minlen` in length. You could fill it in by adapting the final print loop.

---

But, if you're just printing, here is some sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
print_single(const int *height,int len,const char *sex)
{

    printf("\nHeight of %s in descending order\n",sex);

    for (int i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i--)
        printf(" %d", height[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

void
sort_height(int *height,int len)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (len - i - 1); j++) {
            if (height[j] > height[j + 1]) {
                int temp = height[j];
                height[j] = height[j + 1];
                height[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    int heightBoys[] = { 5, 8, 7, 9, 6 };
    int heightGirls[] = { 3, 1, 2 };

    int LENGTH1 = sizeof(heightBoys) / sizeof(heightBoys[0]);
    int LENGTH2 = sizeof(heightGirls) / sizeof(heightGirls[0]);

    sort_height(heightBoys,LENGTH1);
    print_single(heightBoys,LENGTH1,"boys");

    sort_height(heightGirls,LENGTH2);
    print_single(heightGirls,LENGTH2,"girls");

    int minlen = LENGTH1;
    if (minlen > LENGTH2)
        minlen = LENGTH2;

    printf("\n");
    printf("Pairing:\n");
    for (int i = 0;  i < minlen;  ++i)
        printf("Girl:%d Boy:%d\n",heightGirls[i],heightBoys[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Let's say that we input heights and number of them by ourselves. If we have extra heights of boys or girls, how can we output these extra heights apart from the rest?

Two additional `for` loops appended to the bottom should do the trick. In order for this to work, the iteration variable of the final `for` loop in the previous example must be defined *outside* the loop. In other words, notice the definition and usage of `ipair` below.

If you *are* creating an array the type of `struct` that I suggested, these loops can fill it in. The array size would then need to be `max(LENGTH1,LENGTH2)`.

And, in unpaired loops (e.g. for boy 8, the girl value in the struct could be set to 0 or -1 to indicate that the boy is unpaired)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
print_single(const int *height,int len,const char *sex)
{

    printf("\nHeight of %s in descending order\n",sex);

    for (int i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i--)
        printf(" %d", height[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

void
sort_height(int *height,int len)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (len - i - 1); j++) {
            if (height[j] > height[j + 1]) {
                int temp = height[j];
                height[j] = height[j + 1];
                height[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    int heightBoys[] = { 5, 8, 7, 9, 6 };
    int heightGirls[] = { 3, 1, 2 };

    int LENGTH1 = sizeof(heightBoys) / sizeof(heightBoys[0]);
    int LENGTH2 = sizeof(heightGirls) / sizeof(heightGirls[0]);

    sort_height(heightBoys,LENGTH1);
    print_single(heightBoys,LENGTH1,"boys");

    sort_height(heightGirls,LENGTH2);
    print_single(heightGirls,LENGTH2,"girls");

    int minlen = LENGTH1;
    if (minlen > LENGTH2)
        minlen = LENGTH2;

    int ipair = 0;

    printf("\n");
    printf("Pairing:\n");
    for (;  ipair < minlen;  ++ipair)
        printf("Girl:%d Boy:%d\n",heightGirls[ipair],heightBoys[ipair]);

    if (ipair < LENGTH1) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Unpaired Boys:\n");
        for (int i = ipair;  i < LENGTH1;  ++i)
            printf("Boy:%d\n",heightBoys[i]);
    }

    if (ipair < LENGTH2) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Unpaired Girls:\n");
        for (int i = ipair;  i < LENGTH2;  ++i)
            printf("Girl:%d\n",heightGirls[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mean 'pairing' like that. I have one more question. Let's say that we input heights and number of them by ourselves. If we have extra heights of boys or girls, how can we output these extra heights apart from the rest?